# How to include milliseconds in a DateTime user setting?

Tags: c#, datetime, configuration

I have the following user setting defined in app.config:

```
<userSettings>
    <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="LastProcessedDate" serializeAs="String">
            <value>07/06/2010 13:05:10</value>
        </setting>
    </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Is there a way to specify that this setting should be serialized with the milliseconds - e.g. `07/06/2010 13:05:10.181` - so that I can accurately compare it to a SQL Server datetime field?

Comment: Use custom date/time formatting strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't save millisecond values in settings. Deep down in the System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyValue.ConvertObjectToString method the DateTime value is converted to a string using the TypeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString method which doesn't produce milliseconds.

If you really want that level of accuracy and you must save it in the user settings, you should use a different parameter type like string using a custom format that includes milliseconds. None of the standard time formats includes milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for a very simple solution.  I used a setting of type string and called DateTime.Parse when reading the setting and ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff') when writing it.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing it as an `Int64`, which would preserve the entire value of the `DateTime` without any formatting issues or loss of fidelity.